# parsing with text flow

Tags: perl, parsing, text

I have around two pages of text in word format. The text is arranged in two columns. I want to parse the text. However, I am not able to read the first column and then the second column. I don't have any program, as I am not even sure how to start. I was planning to use perl for parsing, but help in any other language would also get me started, or even some general direction.

Comment: M$ Word? Good luck. It's a malformed pile of garbage zipped into an archive...

Comment: The issue is not about reading the text, but reading the text in a particular flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is MSWord, then you can just use the automation model with [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE)

The following code might work for you, or at least get you started:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw<first>;
use Win32::OLE qw<in>;

my $word = Win32::OLE->GetObject( 'C:\Path\Doc.doc' );
my $doc  = $word->{ActiveDocument};
my $col_sect 
    = first { $_-> {PageSetup}{TextColumns}{Count} > 1 } in $doc->Sections
    ;
my $text = $col_sect->{Range}{Text};
```

Comment: You may want to look at Text::Extract::Word, which doesn't depend on OLE and will therefore work on non-Windows systems. (Shamelessly plugging own module...)